# Não consigo criar nova classe no projeto - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, classes

Tenho um projeto onde criei uma novam classe

```
using System;
using Definitions;

namespace CommunicationCheck{

public class CommunicationCheck
{

    private message_struct Send;
    private message_struct Received;

    public CommunicationCheck()
    {
        this.Send = null;
        this.Received = null;

    }

    public MessageSent(message_struct msg)
    {
        this.Send = msg;
    }

    public bool CheckIncomingMessage(message_struct msg)
    {
        if (this.Send.header_byte == msg.header_byte)
        {
            this.Received = msg;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public message_struct GetSend()
    {
        return this.Send;
    }

    public message_struct GetReceived()
    {
        return this.Received;
    }
}

}
```

Dai quando tento add o namespace a outra classe tenho a seguinte mensagem:

[image: Mensagem de erro]

É algum problema de sintaxe ? Como resolver ?

Comment: Tente alterar o nome da classe, para um nome diferente do namespace, ou até mesmo adicionar referência caso seja um projeto distinto do principal.

Comment: Essa classe tá dentro do mesmo projeto?

Comment: Sim, está no mesmo projeto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que aconteceu foi que criei uma classe sem adicioná-la ao meu projeto.
Bastou ir em Projeto -> Add -> Arquivo e selecionar a classe.